# YAML Pipeline Branching Git Error, saying no Git repo found

Tags: git, azure-pipelines, devops, branch, azure-pipelines-yaml

Trying to do a multistage yaml pipeline and running into an issue with Git. My pipeline is starting off with creating a new branch based on the build id, snippet of the code below:

`$exportBranchName = "PipelineRun_BuildId$(Build.BuildId)"`
`cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)`
`git config user.email "pipeline@devops.com"`
`git config user.name "Pipeline"`
`git checkout -b $exportBranchName`
`git push -u origin $exportBranchName`

I'm then calling two separate template files that do slightly different things, however the ending in the templated files to push the changes into the above branch is the same in both.

Strangely the second template file works, but the first fails with the error "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Sample code below that's pushing the changes:

`git fetch`
`$exportBranchName = "PipelineRun_BuildId$(Build.BuildId)"`
`cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)`
`git config user.email "pipeline@devops.com"`
`git config global user.name "Pipeline"`
`git checkout $exportBranchName`
`git add --all`   
`git commit -m "Comiting ${{ parameters.solutionName }} to branch PipelineRun_BuildId$(Build.BuildId)"`
`git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" push --set-upstream origin $exportBranchName`

Just wondering if anyone has an idea to what's causing the first to fail, but not the second?

```
Tried enabling debug on the pipeline, but the logs are showing no obvious changes between the two templated files.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error information `Not a git repository` ,it means that there are no files managed by your git  in this directory.

You should switch the working folder to the repository folder by the command `cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)` firstly.

From your sample code, you use `git fetch` command to download objects but not folder managed under git, so you should change the order:

```
 cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
 git fetch $exportBranchName = "PipelineRun_BuildId$(Build.BuildId)"
```

**update**

Another possible cause of this issue: multiple repositories are checked out in your stage. You can make sure how many repositories you have checked out in your stage.
If you check out multiple repositories, use below command to go into repo folder:

```
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/reponame
```

Comment: Same error happens if I swap the lines around.

Comment: @Nizzy I've updated the answer. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Same error again. I've noticed the following variation between the working template file and the file that errors. The working file on the checkout task states the file path as 'D:\a\1\s' where as the file that errors is 'D:\a\1\s\Source'. However there's nothing that should be changing the file path at this point and this doesn't happen in another DevOps Organisation.

Comment: Can you provide your yaml pipeline script? I want to compare the difference between two templates.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .\ before the Dir name or use the full path.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).